# Is there a way to use the default "built-in" (macro-generated) and only override the single property?

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I'm trying to read the field `vpid` as a string without having to write the entire reads function.

Old code that works, except when `vpid` is an integer.

```
case class SectionProduct(vpid: Option[String], name: Option[String], quantity: Option[Int]) {}

object SectionProduct {
  implicit val config: Aux[WithDefaultValues] = JsonConfiguration[Json.WithDefaultValues](SnakeCase)
  implicit val format: OFormat[SectionProduct] = Json.format[SectionProduct]
  implicit val writes: OWrites[SectionProduct] = Json.writes[SectionProduct]
  // implicit val reads:  Reads[SectionProduct] =   Json.reads[SectionProduct]
}
```

New code, if possible I'm trying to avoid writing out the whole `reads2` block.

```
val intToString: Reads[String] = implicitly[Reads[Int]].map(x => x.toString)

implicit val reads2: Reads[SectionProduct] = (
    ((JsPath \ "vpid").readNullable[String] or (JsPath \ "vpid").readNullable[String](intToString)) and
      (JsPath \ "name").readNullable[String] and
      (JsPath \ "quantity").readNullable[Int]
    ) (SectionProduct.apply _)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play-JSON doesn't provide a per-field configuration for the macro-based codecs, and `vpid` isn't defined with a specific type (there are other optional `String` in the same `SectionProduct`).

With a specific type it can be easily (and can have other benefit aside from this specific usage with improved typing).

```scala
import play.api.libs.json._

final class Vpid(val value: String) extends AnyVal

object Vpid {
  import scala.language.implicitConversions

  @deprecated("Use .value explicitly", "")
  /*
   * {{{
   * val compatStr: String = new Vpid("foo")
   * // => compatStr: String = foo
   * }}}
   */
  implicit def toString(id: Vpid): String = id.value

  implicit def reads: Reads[Vpid] = Json.valueReads[Vpid].orElse(
    implicitly[Reads[Int]].map { i => new Vpid(i.toString) })
}

case class SectionProduct(
  vpid: Option[Vpid],
  name: Option[String],
  quantity: Option[Int])

implicit val reads: Reads[SectionProduct] = Json.reads
```

In which case:

```scala
val input1 = Json.parse("""{
  "vpid": "foo",
  "name": "bar"
}""")

input1.validate[SectionProduct]
// => JsSuccess(SectionProduct(Some(Vpid@18cc6),Some(bar),None),)

val input2 = Json.parse("""{
  "vpid": 1,
  "name": "bar"
}""")

input2.validate[SectionProduct]
// => JsSuccess(SectionProduct(Some(Vpid@31),Some(bar),None),)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and example. I clearly forgot to think outside of the box and just create a new object.

Answer (score 1):

You could preprocess your JSON to make it match the expectations of the macro generated `Reads`:

```
implicit val reads: Reads[SectionProduct] = Json.reads[SectionProduct].preprocess {
    case obj: JsObject =>
      obj.as(
        Reads
          .at[Int](__ \ "vpid")
          .map { vpid => obj + ("vpid" -> JsString(vpid.toString)) }
          .orElse(Reads.pure(obj))
      )
  }
```